# group and count by properties of class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a result class as following

```
class Result:
    cluster = -1;
    label = -1;
```

Both cluster and label can have values between 0-9, what I am trying to do is count number of labels in clusters. Currently I am using the following code to count but it is not an elegant solution. resultList is a list of Result object.

```
countZero = 0;
countOne = 0;
countTwo = 0;
countThree = 0;
countFour = 0;
countFive = 0;
countSix = 0;
countSeven = 0;
countEight = 0;
countNine = 0;

    for i in range(len(resultList)):
        if resultList[i].cluster == 0:
            if resultList[i].label == 0:
                countZero = countZero + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 1:
                countOne = countOne + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 2:
                countTwo = countTwo + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 3:
                countThree = countThree + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 4:
                countFour = countFour + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 5:
                countFive = countFive + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 6:
                countSix = countSix + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 7:
                countSeven = countSeven + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 8:
                countEight = countEight + 1
            if resultList[i].label == 9:
                countNine = countNine + 1

    print(countZero) # 
    print(countOne) # 
    print(countTwo) # 
    print(countThree) #
    print(countFour) # 
    print(countFive) # 
    print(countSix) # 
    print(countSeven) # 
    print(countEight) # 
    print(countNine) #
```

Any advice or guidance in finding a better solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a list of ten numbers, with index 0..9, instead of ten variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the specific count of a label in a cluster, you can create nested dictionaries of the `cluster_id` and the `label_id`:

```py
# Create empty dictionary
cluster_dict = {}
# For 0-9 cluster_id
for cluster_id in range(10):
    # Create a dict for each cluster
    if cluster_id not in cluster_dict.keys():
        cluster_dict[cluster_id] = {}
    # For 0-9 label_id
    for label_id in range(10):
        # Set the cluster/label count to 0
        cluster_dict[cluster_id][label_id] = 0
```

Then you can fill it with the `result_list` values:

```py
for res in result_list:
    cluster_dict[res.cluster][res.label] += 1
```

This lets you access the counts as such, so for cluster 0 and label 2:

```py
cluster_dict[0][2]
```

You can also find the number of results for a given cluster, regardless of label:

```py
sum(cluster_dict[0].values())
```

You can also find the number of results for a given label, regardless of cluster:

```py
sum([count for cluster_id, label_counter in cluster_dict.items() for label_id, count in label_counter.items() if label_id == 2])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

the Counter functions returns a dictionary with the count for each label. Use this for cluster 0 in this way:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(resultList[resultList['cluster']==0]]['label'])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what data structures are for. Here, you could do all that in a few lines using a `dict`:

```
counts = {i:0 for i in range(10)}  # constructs a dict {1: 0} for each number 0-9

for i in range(len(resultList)):
    if resultList[i].cluster == 0:
        counts[resultList[i].label] += 1  # find the count corresponding to the number, and increment it

for k, v in counts:
    print(f"Count {k}: {v}")
```

Comment: Since the keys here are numeric and in order, a list would be better suited than a dict.

Answer (score 1):

```
counts = [0 for x in range(10)]

for i in range(len(resultList)):
    if resultList[i].cluster == 0:
        counts[resultList[i].label] += 1
```

Comment: Using a list like this seems the most straightfoward way to me.

Answer (score 1):

mach easier way

```
import random

class Result:
    def __init__(self ,cluster , label):
        self.label = label
        self.cluster = cluster

# global counter 
counter = {key:0 for key in range(1 , 10)}

# gen random for testing 
lists = [Result(random.randint(0 , 1) , random.randint(1 , 9)) for r in range(1000)]

for result in lists:
    counter[result.label] += 1 if result.cluster == 0 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Along similar lines as other answers but using `defaultdict`. Essentially, a one-liner.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Result:
  def __init__(self, c, l):
    self.cluster = c
    self.label = l

counts = defaultdict(int)

resultList = [Result(1,9), Result(2,1), Result(3, 1), Result(1, 2), Result(1,9)]

for r in resultList:
  counts[(r.cluster, r.label)] += 1

print(counts)
```

Output:
`defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {(1, 9): 2, (2, 1): 1, (3, 1): 1, (1, 2): 1})`